# Dense sift using VLFeat

Tags: matlab, sift, vlfeat

I am having trouble understanding the dense sift documentation in **vlfeat** shown at http://www.vlfeat.org/matlab/vl_dsift.html. They have mentioned a `bin size` parameter for the width of the grid at a pixel and have mentioned a `step` parameter for vertical and horizontal displacement.

I test these parameters using the following code

```
[f, d] = vl_dsift(single(image), 'size', 16 , 'step' , 5 ) ;
```

where my image is a 50X50 matrix. I expect the keyframes to start from (1,1) move to (1,6) #displacement of 5 horizontally and so on.

But the result that I get has only 1 sift descriptor at `(25,25)` point.

Does anyone know what these parameters actually mean and if I am applying them correctly ? Is there any way to apply it in the above mentioned pattern (starting from top left with vertical and horizontal displacement of step size apart from manually getting the locations)

Answer (score 1):

They wrote

> The scale of the extracted descriptors is controlled by the option
>   SIZE, i.e. the width in pixels of a spatial bin (recall that a SIFT
>   descriptor is a spatial histogram with 4 x 4 bins).

So, it computes SIFT of the square part of the image with size 4*16 = 64 x 64 pixels. Your whole image is less than needed area for computation.  I`m wondering, why you get even that one. 
Also, even if it would be big enough, you cannot calculate SIFT of the point (1,1), because there is only south-east part of the patch is defined, others are outside the image.